# Windows PowerShell - implement c# interface with reserved words as method names

Tags: powershell

In order to call a c# API, I need to implement an interface that uses `Process` as a method name. The problem is `Process` is a reserved (key)word in PowerShell. This works just fine for PowerShell (core) 7.2+ but not for Windows PowerShell. There, it fails with obscure syntax errors referring to other parts of the script and I was only able to pinpoint the issue by removing all the other code. This way I've found out that renaming the `Process` method to anything else, even just adding an underscore, fixes the issue.

The problem is I cannot rename the method while keeping the interface implemented. And I need the interface implementation in order to pass the object to a c# method that requires it as an argument. Is there any way to escape the method name in Windows Powershell? Or alternatively, some other way to add the method & the info that the class implements the interface with reflection or sth similar?

The simplified code looks like this:

```
class StackTraceProcessor:Sentry.Extensibility.ISentryEventProcessor
{
    [Sentry.SentryEvent]Process([Sentry.SentryEvent] $event_)
    {
        return $null
    }
}
```

And the errors I'd get in Windows PowerShell:

```
At C:\dev\sentry-powershell\module\private\StackTraceProcessor.ps1:4 char:25
+     [Sentry.SentryEvent]Process([Sentry.SentryEvent] $event_)
+                         ~
Missing a property name or method definition.
At C:\dev\sentry-powershell\module\private\StackTraceProcessor.ps1:4 char:5
+     [Sentry.SentryEvent]Process([Sentry.SentryEvent] $event_)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At C:\dev\sentry-powershell\module\private\StackTraceProcessor.ps1:9 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncompleteMemberDefinition

At C:\dev\sentry-powershell\module\private\StackTraceProcessor.ps1:4 char:25
+     [Sentry.SentryEvent]Process([Sentry.SentryEvent] $event_)
+                         ~
Missing a property name or method definition.
At C:\dev\sentry-powershell\module\private\StackTraceProcessor.ps1:4 char:5
+     [Sentry.SentryEvent]Process([Sentry.SentryEvent] $event_)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At C:\dev\sentry-powershell\module\private\StackTraceProcessor.ps1:9 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncompleteMemberDefinition
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no elegant(*) workaround for this parsing bug, and unless you want to jump through some extraordinary hoops, using `Add-Type` to compile an implementation from C# source is probably the easiest solution here:

```bash
Add-Type @'
public class StackTraceProcessor : Sentry.Extensibility.ISentryEventProcessor
{
    public Sentry.SentryEvent Process(Sentry.SentryEvent event_)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
'@ -ReferencedAssemblies path\to\sentry.dll
```

---

*) There *are* other ways to have a dynamic type implement an interface at runtime, including:

1. constructing and emitting the implementing type yourself (see below), or
2. manually constructing the requisite AST for your `class` statement (thus side-stepping the parsing validation of the keyword `process`)

I've deliberately not shown the latter approach because the required code is 1) even messier than manually emitting the type, and 2) much more prone to version incompatibility due to changes in the underlying private API.

---

Alternatively, you can use the `[Reflection.Emit]` API - basically mirroring what PowerShell's internal compiler would have done with your `class` statement if the parser didn't get in the way.

Beware that if you're doing anything more complicated than returning arguments as-is, **this is going to be painful to construct**, as you'll need to provide MSIL instructions in place of method-body source code:

```bash
# define assembly and module builder
$name = "CustomInMemoryAssembly_$(Get-Random)"
$asmName = [System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::new($name)
$asmBuilder = [System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder]::DefineDynamicAssembly($asmName, [System.Reflection.AssemblyBuilderAccess]::Run)
$moduleBuilder = $asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("${name}__module$(Get-Random)")

# define dynamic type builder, specify interface implemented
$typeName = 'StackTraceProcessor'
$typeAttributes = [System.Reflection.TypeAttributes]'AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public'
$typeParent = [object]
$typeInterfaces = [type[]]@([Sentry.Extensibility.ISentryEventProcessor])

$typeBuilder = $moduleBuilder.DefineType($typeName, $typeAttributes, $typeParent, $typeInterfaces)

# define required interface member
$methodName = 'Process'
$methodAttributes = [System.Reflection.MethodAttributes]'Public, Virtual'
$methodReturnType = [Sentry.SentryEvent]
$methodParameterTypes = [type[]]@([Sentry.SentryEvent])

$methodBuilder = $typeBuilder.DefineMethod($methodName, $methodAttributes, $methodReturnType, $methodParameterTypes)

# define method body contents 
$methodILGenerator = $methodBuilder.GetILGenerator()

###################################
# The following MSILinstructions  #
# will return the first parameter #
# argument, ie. `return event_;`  #
#                                 #
#   ldarg.1                       #
#   ret                           #
#                                 #
##################################
$methodILGenerator.Emit([System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes]::Ldarg_1)
$methodILGenerator.Emit([System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes]::Ret)

# close and output new defined type
$sentryProcessorType = $typeBuilder()
```

Now you can do:

```bash
$sentryProcessor = $sentryProcessorType::new()
# pass implementation to consumer
$sentryEventConsumer.ProcessEvents($sentryProcessor)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Disclaimer

Thanks to the answer by @mathias-r-jessen (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78001981/2386130), I've been able to make this work by adding a separate abstract c# class implementing the interface, that just forwards `Process` to the abstract `DoProcess`. This base class is then used in PowerShell which this way compiles just fine.

I'm adding following pieces of code as a separate answer as a helpful tip for future readers but keeping Mathias's one as the accepted answer because it is indeed the one that helped me resolved this. Although I knew about [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type), it didn't occur to me to use it myself.

---

#### `SentryEventProcessor.cs`

```cs
// This is an abstract class for any PowerShell event processors. It gets around an issue with Windows PowerShell
// failing to compile scripts that have a method name `Process`, which is a reserved word.
public abstract class SentryEventProcessor : Sentry.Extensibility.ISentryEventProcessor
{
    public Sentry.SentryEvent Process(Sentry.SentryEvent event_)
    {
        return DoProcess(event_);
    }

    protected abstract Sentry.SentryEvent DoProcess(Sentry.SentryEvent event_);
}
```

#### `StackTraceProcessor.ps1`

```
class StackTraceProcessor : SentryEventProcessor
{
    [Sentry.SentryEvent]DoProcess([Sentry.SentryEvent] $event_)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

#### Module code

One thing to note here is that `Add-Type` cannot be in the same file as the derived `StackTraceProcessor`, because the base class wouldn't be defined yet when the script is "sourced". Instead, we need to compile the c# first.

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition (Get-Content ".../SentryEventProcessor.cs" -Raw) -ReferencedAssemblies $sentryDllPath

. ".../StackTraceProcessor.ps1"
```

Comment: Nice compromise, I like it! If you're working on a module you can put the `Add-Type` call in a separate script and reference it in the `ScriptsToProcess` entry in your module manifest - that way you don't need to worry about whether the wrapper class has been loaded by the time the script module loads

Comment: yes, that's basically what I've done.

Also, thanks.